# informatica-powercenter Mapping variable in Java

Tags: informatica-powercenter

How do I access a mapping parameter (`$$myvariable`)  from a Java Transformation in Informatica Powercenter?

What I want to do is to make a Java transformation reusable by making a part of it configurable, and a variable seemed suitable for that, however I haven't been able to access (read) a variable from the Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three options

- use an expression transformation with a variable port that passes
  the variable into an input port defined in the java transformation
- Use shell variables and get them with the Java 'System.getenv' call for example:

  `final String myconfig = System.getenv("MYCONFIG");`
- use a Java expression to get to the variable

  `Integer getEmpID()  throws SDKException
  {
  return (Integer)invokeJExpression("SETCOUNTVARIABLE($$MyVar)", new Object [] {} );
  }`